# How to submit form data via ajax if form is also loaded via ajax and that ajax loaded file have more than one form?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, web

after spending lots of time on this, finally i decided to post here .
actually i'm trying to make a single page webapp so due to this the contact form is loaded via ajax '.load()' function :

```
    $('.formWrap').load('contactForm.html',function(){
```

after loading successfully, I tried to use ajax for submission process, so I used this code :

```
 var form = {
    load: function(){
          $('.formWrap').load('contactForm.html',function(){
            form.formFunc.formBind();
          });
     ***form.click();***
    },
  ****click: function(){
$('html').on("click","#contactSubmitButton",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.formFunc.sidebarvalidateForm($(this).attr('data-formId'));
});
   },****
 formFunc: {
formBind: function(){
        $('#sidebarformSuccessMessageWrap').hide();
    $('.sidebarformValidationError').hide();
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-dummy')){
            $(this).val('');
        };
    });

    $('input, textarea').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){    
            $(this).val($(this).attr('data-dummy'));
        };
    });
},
sidebarsubmitData: function(currentForm, formType){    
    Anu.Config.sidebarformSubmitted = 'true';
    var formInput = $('#' + currentForm).serialize();
    $.post($('#' + currentForm).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
        $('#' + currentForm).hide();
        $('#sidebarformSuccessMessageWrap').fadeIn(500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#sidebarformSuccessMessageWrap').fadeOut(500);
            $('#successinfo').fadeIn(500);
            $('.contact-form').slideUp("slow", function() {
                $('.contact-form').hide();
            });
        },5000);
    });
},
sidebarvalidateForm: function(currentForm, formType){
    $('.sidebarformValidationError').hide();
    $('.sidebarfieldHasError').removeClass('sidebarfieldHasError');
    $('#' + currentForm + ' .sidebarrequiredField').each(function(i){  
        if($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-dummy')){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('data-dummy'));
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).addClass('fieldHasError');
            $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'Error').show();
            return false;  
        };
        if($(this).hasClass('sidebarrequiredEmailField')){  
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var tempField = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            if(!emailReg.test($(tempField).val())) {
                $(tempField).focus();
                $(tempField).addClass('sidebarfieldHasError');
                $(tempField + 'Error2').show();
                return false;
            };
        };
        if(Anu.Config.sidebarformSubmitted == 'false' && i == $('#' + currentForm + ' .sidebarrequiredField').length - 1){
            Anu.formFunc.sidebarsubmitData(currentForm, formType);
        };  
      });
}
 }
 }
```

and call this function as :

```
   $(document).ready(form.load);
```

and the form html (contactForm.html) code is :
***[there are 6 forms on this file with different FORM IDs. but field className are same. I post here only one form, all others are same]***

```
 <form class="contactForm" id="contactForm" action='contact-send.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                        <span class="sidebarformValidationError" id="contactNameFieldError">
                                            <div class="sidebar-small-notification">
                                                <p>Error Sending! Please enter your name!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span>             
                                        <span class="sidebarformValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError">
                                            <div class="sidebar-small-notification">
                                                <p>Error Sending! Mail address required!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span> 
                                        <span class="sidebarformValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError2">
                                            <div class="sidebar-small-notification">
                                                <p>Error Sending! Valid Email Address Required</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span> 
                                       <span class="sidebarformValidationError" id="contactSubjectFieldError">
                                            <div class="sidebar-small-notification">
                                                <p>Error Sending! Subject field is empty!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span> 
                                        <span class="sidebarformValidationError" id="contactMessageTextareaError">
                                            <div class="sidebar-small-notification">
                                                <p>Error Sending! Message field is empty!</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </span> 
                        <input type="text" class="sidebar-input required sidebarrequiredField first" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name" required name="contactNameField" id="contactNameField" /><span class="clear-input"></span>
                        <input type="text" class="sidebar-input sidebarrequiredEmailField required sidebarrequiredField" placeholder="Email" required name="contactEmailField" id="contactEmailField" /><span class="clear-input"></span>
                        <input type="text" class="sidebar-input required sidebarrequiredField" placeholder="Subject" required name="contactSubjectField" id="contactSubjectField" /><span class="clear-input"></span>
                        <textarea class="sidebar-textarea required sidebarrequiredField last" required placeholder="Enter Your message Here" name="contactMessageTextarea" id="contactMessageTextarea"></textarea><span class="clear-area"></span>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="sidebar-button" id="contactSubmitButton" data-formId="contactForm"/>
                    </form>
```

now. with this code, I'm unable to submit the form data. When all fields are filled and submit button is clicked than in the place of submittibg the data it shows the first field validation error message.
And I think that the root o this  problem is : having more than one form with same className fields. So when I press submit button, it check the same field from other forms.

Than my actual question is : how can I use ajax to submit form data if form is loaded via ajax and have more than one form (contact, inquiry, complaint, other etc).

Thanks and Regrads

Comment: Some code formatting would help

Comment: You should override the default form behaviour by using `.submit()` inside of your binding method. Put your AJAX call inside the `.submit()`

Comment: @NabilKadimi : Sorry, I forget to add the 'click' function code, now its added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form. Fill that form with data. And using jQuery send the data via `$("form").submit`

Comment: Are you having full form filled?

Comment: Actually the problem is that : validation function works well untill one field is empty, but when all fields are dully filled, than vakidation function thrown error from the first field, in the place of submitting it.

Comment: What error it is? I am not sure that there is any error. Ok, try out this: Open IE in there press F12 to open Developer Tools. That will let you know what requests are being sent and which one not.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it n let you know

Comment: When all fields are empty, n submit button is pressed, than its shows the msg according to the id of 'sidrbarfieldValidationError'. But when all fields are filled, than in the place of submitting the data it show first field error message ('#contactNameFieldError'). But it works well when the form is not an ajax loaded form.

Comment: If you are using Laptop, you might consider pressing fn too!

Comment: In this case there is some issue with the Ajax request. Can I see you code?

Comment: Yup, I'm using laptop. The code is already posted in my question.